# I get a blast of hot air during stop start driving. What could cause this?

Tags: clutch, hyundai, diesel, shifting, heat

I am a learner driver with a Hyundai i20. Every now and then when I stop and then go and switch to second gear I get a blast of heat at my legs and feet. The aircon is off and its a diesel.

I am thinking it because of switching to fast over to second or maybe leaving the clutch in a bit too long.

hyundai i20

Comment: On a side note, please consider updating your answer with better grammar, spelling and punctuation.

Comment: If you depress the clutch pedal completely, then the engine and transmission are disengaged, so I don't think that is the issue. Is this issue only happening when you switch to second gear? Maybe you are driving too fast and shifting too early.

Comment: Also remove the carpet and check for any holes. It could be that you there is some kind of dent/whole/rust which is causing air to be blown in from the engine/transmission bay to the footwell.

Comment: If you direct the "vent" selection off your feet do you still get this blast of air?  It may be that the action of pressing the clutch places your ankle in close proximity to the lower vents?

Comment: It happens only when I go from first to second.I do a lot of short distantce driving.Think it happened once in third gear.It does not happen every time just some cases where I pull away at a stop sign and when the engine sound like it battling or climbing revs I put over to second gear.The I20 shows when to put over into second but a lot of times I put it into second gear before it shows I must

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking @SteveMatthews may be onto something - If the HVAC system is vacuum operated, one of the vacuum actuators is having an issue (ie: leaking). It may be getting adjusted without you having to do anything. When you shift gears, you take your foot off of the "go pedal" (not a gas pedal in this instance because it's diesel power ;-)), which causes a vacuum spike in the intake manifold. This spike could be translating directly to the vacuum actuator causing it to manipulate the blend door or outside air control door, causing you to get a blast of unwanted hot air.

**NOTE:** This is all conjecture at this point. This would especially be moot if there are manual (ie: cable controls) in the HVAC system in your vehicle.